# How can I export data from a c-tree program?

Tags: database, export, ctree, c-treeace

I'm in the process of consolidating our old stuff into TFS. One of the old things is a bug report repository. I believe it's using c-tree to store data, because it has .idx and .dat files. Id like to try to export all of this data into a txt/csv so someone else can sort through what is still relevant, and the import the good stuff into TFS.

The problem is I'm not sure how to go about exporting the data from the c-tree files. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Makolyte

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to any Faircom tools or APIs, http://www.faircom.com/ace/support_doc_t.php would be a good place to start.

Otherwise, you can get an express edition of C-treeACE here: http://www.faircom.com/ace/download_t.php